# Module Tab is missing while creating Headless Site

Tags: jss, sxa-jss

I am creating a `Headless` site using below Sitecore version on my local machine. While creating the new headless site, I don't see Module tab in the popup.

1. Sitecore 10.2.0 rev. 006766 (WDP XP0 packages)
2. Sitecore Headless Services Server XM 20.0.0 rev. 00539

Here is the screenshot, Module tab is missing.

[image: Missing Module Tab]

Thanks,
Salim

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue, This is out of the box Sitecore behavior. It is available from Sitecore 10.2 Update 1.